# Whats keeping my contact form from working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, contacts

I have been trying to get my contact form working but I just cant. No error message or anything that could give me a lead. Here are my three parts:

```
<div class="contact-form">
<h3>Contact Info</h3>

<address>
<strong>MY WEBSITE</strong>
</address>

<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="contactname" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone#" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">


<select name="interest">
<option value="choose" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Choose your interest</option>
<option value="help">Help</option>
<option value="naturalproducts">Natural Products</option>
<option value="other">Other</option>

</select>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Brief Message" required></textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
</form>
</div>
```

My sendemail.php goes like this:

```
<?php
$contactname       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactname'])); 
$from              = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$phone             = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])); 
$selected          = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['selected'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'info@mywebsite.com';//replace with your email

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
```

Last, the javascript with the message goes like this:

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Comment: `mail` has a string as its fourth parameter, not an array. Perhaps `implode ('\r\n', $headers)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

By default `$.ajax` does a GET request, you have to actually tell it to do a POST request, and you're listening for `$_POST[]` values, so that's probably what you want to do.

You can get the type of request from the forms `method` attribute, and you have to send the form data as well.

```
$.ajax({
    url  : $(this).attr('action'),
    type : $(this).attr('method'),
    data : $(this).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
    }
}).done(function(data){
    form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: I tried this as well with no luck. Could something else be breaking my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any form data and you are not using the `POST` HTTP method but you are looking at the `$_POST` variable.

```
$.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(), // send data
        method: "POST", // send post method
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
```

also you must make your headers a string. try `implode("\n", $headers)` as mentioned by @andrewsi.

Comment: I tried this still does not work. Been scratching my head for a few days.

Comment: Have you tested just sending a simple message via `php` on your server. e.g. `mail("me@mysite", "testing subject", "here comes the body");` ?

Comment: I simplified the form (no js no css styling) and it worked. It is somewhere on the js. ALso, the ajax takes me to a second page & the message is not delivered.

Comment: Can you open your debugger and see if there is any error message in the console?

Comment: no errors. I will go back to the drawing board . Thanks

Comment: can you put in a `console.log()` into your submit to see if it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
 var form = $('#main-contact-form');
 form.submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: $(this).attr('action'),
         data: form.serialize(),
         beforeSend: function(){
             form.prepend(
                 form_status
                     .html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>')
                     .fadeIn()
             );
         }
     }).done(function(data){
         form_status
             .html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>')
             .delay(3000)
             .fadeOut();
     });
 });
```